# Hide the labels in the pie graph in echart by baidu

Tags: pie-chart, donut-chart, baidu, echarts

I am referring to this https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/example/pie1.html#-en example. I am not able to hide the adjacent labels in the pie graph. I have encircled one of the labels I wish to hide in the attached image. Kindly help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: works if you include in the 'series' tag portion of the options

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. I had to include the following code into the options and it worked:

```
itemStyle : {
              normal : {
                         label : {
                                   show : false
                                  },
                         labelLine : {
                                       show : false
                                      }
                         }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically hide the label and labelline, while passing the data to the pi-chart, you can use the following properties

```
{ value: 1, name: 'Open', label: { show: false }, labelLine: { show: false } },
{ value: 3, name: 'In Progress', label: { show: false }, labelLine: { show: false } },
{ value: 2, name: 'Done', label: { show: false }, labelLine: { show: false } }
```